# How to make a function shorter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have this function which works but I am trying to make it as short as possible. Something like: return [result(result += word[0]) for word in text]. Basically in one line, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def first_letter(text):
    text = text.upper().split()
    result = ''
    for word in text:
        result += word[0]
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_letter(text):
    return "".join([word[0] for word in text.upper().split()])
```

Comment: join works with generators too. `[]` can be removed from its argument. `join(word[0]...)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Can be even shorter (ignoring the import statement) using regex substitution.

```
import re
def first_letter(text):
  return re.sub(r"(\S)\w*\s*", r"\1", text.upper())
```